# Get count of mysql response result like 'SHOW OPEN TABLES'

Tags: mysql

I am looking to check if there are any locked queries running on the database before i flush temporary tables on my system, for the same i am getting the query
`SHOW OPEN TABLES WHERE In_use > 0;`

But this results a table and i cant get the count of the table size internally,

i tried with a query as below

`select count(*) from (SHOW OPEN TABLES where In_use > 0) a;`

But this didnt help me out, let me know how can i achieve this

i am looking to get the result data of system information and check if there is any real transaction happening or lock running.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using SHOW OPEN TABLES ,This does not query locked transactions，you can use this sql:

```
select *  
from sys.innodb_lock_waits a, information_schema.innodb_trx b  
where a.blocking_trx_id = b.trx_id \G
```

Comment: I recommend using proper join syntax.

Comment: I am not looking for any references, i would like to know if there is a lock on any table before i run a delete query for a temporary table, i plan to get list of tables locked at that moment and then run a delete if no locks are enabled on the tables.